# Pagination: Nothing appears on 2nd page

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I've been using this pagination for some other projects of mine before, and they seem to work... however now I'm trying this, it can list everything on page 1, but as soon as I go to page 2 there are no results at all (even though there are more than 5 rows available in the database)

It's late night and I might be blind, but this is really disturbing. Any clue of why it's not showing up anything on page 2 and further?

```
<?php

    // Prepare pagination
    $getPage = $_GET["page"];
    if(isset($getPage)) { $page  = $getPage; } else { $page = 1; }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 

    // Get articles
    $Listquery = $LibraryArticle->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM site_articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, 5");
    while($fetchlistquery = $Listquery->fetch_array()) {

    $article_content = (strlen($fetchlistquery['article_desc']) > 244) ? substr($fetchlistquery['article_desc'],0,245).'...' : $fetchlistquery['article_desc'];
?>
    <div id="news_container">
        <img src="<?php echo $fetchlistquery["article_img"]; ?>" class="newsbox-style" />
        <div class="news-title"><?php echo $fetchlistquery["article_title"]; ?></div>
        <?php echo $article_content; ?>
        <div class="read-more"><a href="">Read more</a> &rightarrow;</div>
        <br style="clear: both;">
    </div>
<?php
    }

    // Intiate pagination
    $countarticles = $LibraryArticle->mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM site_articles");
    $row = $countarticles->fetch_row();
    $total_records = $row[0]; 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 5);

    echo "<div style='float:right;'>";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) { 
        echo "<a href='?page=".$i."'><div class='news-pagi'>".$i."</div></a>"; 
    } 

    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the query executed to display the second page? Can you either dump it, or get it from the MySQL general log?

Comment: You have `$start_from = ($page-1) * 20;`, so unless you have over `40` rows, then on page `2` it will not return anything. I assume since you have `... LIMIT $start_from, 5"` and `$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 5);`, you meant to do ``$start_from = ($page-1) * 5;` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Sean. Weirdly enough I tried exactly that before and nothing changed, oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing this is a quick mod to test the pagination with only a few rows on your database, but you are showing only 5 rows per page but your `$start_from` is being incremented by `$page * 20`

```
// Prepare pagination
$getPage = $_GET["page"];
if(isset($getPage)) { $page  = $getPage; } else { $page = 1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; //  <-- change to 5

// Get articles
$Listquery = $LibraryArticle->mysqli->query("SELECT * 
                                             FROM site_articles 
                                             ORDER BY id DESC 
                                             LIMIT $start_from, 5");
// or change LIMIT to 20
```

Comment: No, done the exact same thing myself... more than once @Fred-ii-